# How to Display a Custom Field Value of a Taxonomy in Post Page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

This seems very straight forward, but I can't get it to work even after going through the documentation (and a number of questions in this site) multiple times.

I have a custom post type called `comic` with a taxonomy field (type radio button) called `book`. The `book` taxonomy has a text field called `book_title`. I'm trying to display the value of `book_title` in `single-comic.php`.

This is what I've done so far:

```
<?php 
$term = get_field('book');
if( $term ): ?>
<h1><?php echo $term->book_title; ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This results in an empty `h1` element, which suggests that `$term` returns `true`. Also, echoing `$term` returns `9` which I believe is the number of fields (default and custom) associated with `book` taxonomy. This means that I'm getting the correct object. I'm just unable to use it to display the values of its fields.

Comment: 9 should be the ID of the term. You still need to go get the term object.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get array in a multi dimensional format so you cannot fetch directly like you have implemented. To fetch respective field you need to loop the $terms array. Please try below snippet. Hope it works.

```
<?php 

$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'book');

if( $terms ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

        <h1><?php echo $term->book_title; ?></h1>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Make sure that the Return Value must be tweak between the `Term Object` and `Term ID`. Keep the Return value to `Term Object`

Comment: Thank you so much! I change `get_field` to `get_terms`, now it works :)

Comment: Sorry, `get_terms` returns all terms of the specified taxonomy. To get terms attached to post, `get_the_terms` should be used instead. Please correct the answer so I can put back the tick mark.

Comment: It seems to be fine now @Sheedo